# Pegando arquivo xlsx com HTML e PHP

Tags: php, html

Preciso fazer a importação de dados *xlsx* para um sistema que criei.

**HTML**

```html
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo">
    <input type="submit" name="pegar value="pegar">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['pega'])) {

   $arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
   $file = fopen($arquivo,"r");

   while(! feof($file)){
       echo fgets($file). "<br />";
   }

   fclose($file);
}
```

E essas são as mensagens, de erro, que aparecem:

> Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given
>   in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/scripts_da_web/php/importaCSV.php
>   on line 20
>
> Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/scripts_da_web/php/importaCSV.php
>   on line 22
>
> Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/scripts_da_web/php/importaCSV.php
>   on line 24

Comment: Faz o upload do arquivo antes de abrir, depois vc deleta ela com `unlink()`

Comment: Desculpe @rray, não entendi. Fazer o upload antes?

Comment: Sim, use `move_uploaded_file`, lembre que `$_FILES` é um array, de um `print_r()` para ver a informação contida nele.

Comment: Com print_r() apareceu isso:

Array ( [name] => Fluxo de caixa VP 1015.xlsx [type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet [tmp_name] => /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpCIgXr7 [error] => 0 [size] => 76347 )

Comment: Alguém por favor, pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É mais fácil você fazer isso utilizando o padrão de arquivos CSV (separado por vírgula).
Use a library PHPExcel para converter o seu arquivo xlsx para csv, e em seguida use a função fgetcsv para transformar os dados do csv em um array no php. Instale a lib e complete seu código com algo assim:

```
$file = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
$csvFileName = str_replace('.xlsx', '.csv', $file);
$objWriter->save($csvFileName);
if (($handle = fopen($csvFileName, "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num campos na linha $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Links úteis:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Da onde vem `$file`?

Comment: $file seria o caminho completo do arquivo xlsx que você deseja tratar

Comment: No caso dele o arquivo vem via `$_FILES`.

Comment: Vou tentar, mais tarde, isso @LFZiron. Valeu.
Mas dai terei que baixar a classe do PHPExcel, certo?

Comment: É só dar um include da classe PHPExcel.php e colocar os código acima @LFZiron?

Comment: @LFZiron, chamei a classe, e pus seu código, mas aparece o seguinte aviso na tela:

"Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/scripts_da_web/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 342

Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/scripts_da_web/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 343
"

Comment: Alguém por favor, pode me ajudar?

Comment: Coloque antes do código que eu te passei:

$file = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];

Comment: Não vi que você tinha respondido.
Já tinha feito isso.
Agora está funcionando, o problema é que os dados de cada célula são exibidos, um abaixo do outro na tela e deveria estar aparecendo 3 dados, um ao lado do outro e assim por diante, entende?